# Livewire component doesn't refresh fully after emit

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

livewire component doesn't refresh fully after emit from another component, It displays some missing part. Is there any fix to this?

[image]

My livewire component

```
    class AllStaffs extends Component
{
    // public $staffs;
    use WithPagination;
    protected $listeners = ['addedStaff' => 'render',
        'editedStaff' => 'render',
        'render'];

    public function delete($id)
    {
        User::destroy($id);
        $this->emitSelf('render');
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('staff-deleted');
        session()->flash('success', 'Staff Deleted Successfully !');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $roles = Role::all();
        $staffs = User::latest()->paginate(10);
        // $staffs = $this->staffs;
        return view('livewire.all-staffs', compact('staffs', 'roles'));
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to share some code, this could happen for a number of reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the troubleshooting section of livewire docs
set the wire key on each table 
wire:key="foo"